Should we create token questions for some problems that come up often?
Some basic questions come up every now and then, like "why am I stuck synchronizing at X?". Most of them are dealing with some specific user issue, so creating an answer encompassing all variants of the issue might be an overkill. Should we create some token questions on a few common, key issues that are often encountered and answer them very meticulously, trying to cover every aspect of the problem the user might face?

I think we should create a couple token questions on a few subjects that come up if the questions we have so far on the same subject are too localized.
For example, there are two questions on synchronizing with the network and downloading a blockchain [1], [2], both being a bit localized with their back story and answers that cover part of the problems a user might face - not knowing what synchronizing it, being stuck at some block. We also have a question about initial connecting to the network, and probably could cover such aspects as "why is this so slow?".
Hopefully an exhaustive question like that with an exhaustive answer would cover all future problems anyone can have (even if they are not aware of some aspects of the problem).

Definitely! Go for it.

I've started a collection of canonical questions and answers.

This generalized might be a candidate token question: How can I convert Bitcoins for withdrawal to PLN (to currency C from A via BTC)
